# Sample application using Google.Protobuf and C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Any sources for sample application using Google.Protobuf and C# .Net 4.7.2?

Found a couple of examples: [Example1](https://putridparrot.com/blog/using-protobuf-net-in-c/)

[Example2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/protobuf-in-c-sharp)

protobuf-net is a .NET library around the Google Protocol Buffers.
Other one is Google.Protobuf with .Net core.

Is it possible to serialize as JSON  or some other object instead of write to a file?
For example put serialized data to a queue or db for other process to consume.

If your class is of type ProtoContract, can you still have constructor?

Comment: There's a lot of barely related themes in here. Firstly, protobuf-net only deals with the binary protobuf format, not the opinionated JSON dialect; the Google library handles both, but you mention ProtoContract, so: which are you using? Constructor: for protobuf-net, yes, do what you like, but protobuf-net will need to fine a parameterless constructor (it can be private), or specify SkipConstructor=true in the ProtoContract. Examples: tons of them; doing what?

Comment: This will be first time using protobuf. So still exploring options. I want to JSON serialize an object from C# app and put it on a bus for other process (of any language) to be able to de-serialize and consume it. In that case looks like I need a sample C# .net 4.7.2 (not .Net Core) example implementation that's using google protobuf

Comment: if you want JSON, why would you focus on a protobuf tool? I mean, the Google library supports a very opinionated version of JSON, but for JSON in general: *just use any JSON serializer*!?

Comment: @MarcGravell Got it. With byte[], if I use protobuf-net, do the other end consumer app needs to be using same package and C# or it can use google protobuf with python/Java or something and still convert byte[] back to object?

Comment: the binary payload is cross-platform - it doesn't matter what language/framework they're using, if that's what you're asking - that is largely the point of protobuf

Comment: Yes. looking at protobuf-net, you decorate your class with ProtoContract and ProtoMember. So no proto file etc, How will proto deserializer that's using different programming language or even different C# solution other end know the contract or object structure?

Comment: indeed, for cross-platform work you'll want the .proto - `Serializer.GetProto<T>` gives you what the library thinks of your contract, or if you want you can start from a .proto and have the tooling generate the classes from there